# Do parallel octaves "count" across multiple voices?

Tags: voice-leading

I'm really not sure of a better way to phrase my question.
If the tenor and alto voices are both on a B, and the tenor voice moves down to A, does it count as parallel octaves if the soprano voice moves down to an A on the next downbeat? (I've attached a screenshot of the measures in question.)

[image: Parallel octaves?]

Comment: Yes. What matters, I think, is that it *sounds* like parallel octaves. There are also parallel octaves - soprano and bass - on the first and second chords.

Comment: I’m interested in this passage. 1. Could you show more bares? 2. Is this a given tune to harmonize? 3. Is this an existing passage of a song or a task? 4. Is the bass or the soprano given? Can we choose/change the chord progression?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian you might think that the answer is "yes," but there are plenty of examples "out in the wild" of part writing that does this.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli this was a small portion of a harmonization I'm working on for a melody. It's intended to be part of a larger piece eventually....

Comment: @phoog There are indeed. And plenty of examples of parallel fifths and octaves.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian not much in the renaissance and baroque, which are the periods I was thinking of when I left that comment.  I'm mostly thinking of pieces in 5 parts or more, where there's sometimes a good deal of jumping around to avoid parallel fifths and octaves, but if you play the parts on a keyboard you get parallel fifths and octaves.

Comment: Athanasius gave you the answer. But, if you are trying to learn common practice voice leading (Bach, Mozart, etc.) I think it's better to learn what _good voice leading and harmony is_ rather than a list of prohibitions.

Comment: all answers tell something useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it depends on your classification system.  The aural result in this case would definitely sound a bit like parallel octaves, even though the octaves only occur by the confluence of bits from three different voices.

This occurs in this particular example because there's a voice *overlap* in soprano and alto, where the soprano leaps below the last alto note.  That's generally not good voice-leading in four-part chorale style (though it may be acceptable in other stylistic contexts).

There also is what's known as *direct fifths* or *hidden fifths* between the soprano and tenor, where they both move in the same direction toward an octave, which will accent the octave a bit.  But they are generally not considered a serious problem unless between outer voices.

So, basically, you have the combined problems of *voice overlap* in S-A with the *direct fifths* in S-T, which end up also creating parallel octaves within the texture as a whole.  Whether or not you want to call these truly "parallel octaves" (which often has the implication of two specific voices moving in parallel), there are enough voice-leading problems to make some changes here.

Comment: Interesting--I hadn't heard of direct fifths before. I'm fairly new to composition in general (and voice leading, specifically), but I'll see how I can rethink the chord structures.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is the reason for the "rule" that voices should not overlap. In the particular example, the treble A is lower than the preceding alto B.

The fix here is easy enough - just change the alto from B to G, which gives you a better voicing of that chord anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Do parallel octaves “count” across multiple voices?

No.

Parallel motion is between *two voices*.

But it isn't clear what you mean by "count."

By *definition* the movement in question is not parallel octaves and in that sense it doesn't "count."

If "count" means "something to avoid," then the question is about *style.* For that concern you need to both identify the motion type properly *and* understand what motion is considered good in a particular style.

From *Kostka, Tonal Harmony* an example of *misidentified* parallel fifths which would be acceptable for 18th century style voice leading...

[image]

So, the movement you asked about is not parallel octaves, but there are other problems with voice leading in your example:

- parallel octaves between bass and soprano in the first two chords
- unbalanced/incomplete chord tones in the second chord
- crossed voices between soprano and alto
- direct fifths in outer voices to the `D` major chord

It's a drag to write something, then proof it against of voice leading prohibitions. I suggest getting a few harmony or counterpoint textbooks and review the part writing procedures. Better books (for me that was Piston's *Harmony* first edition) will what you should do and why rather than list prohibitions. Procedures like...

- voice chord completely
- hold common tones
- move voices by step, etc.

Combine that with a review of the *rule of the octave* (an old method of teaching harmony, short and simple but goes a *long* way for understanding) and you should get a handle on 18th century voice leading and harmony.